# How to fix a url path that keeps repeating the prefix

Tags: php, asp.net

I'm currently trying to migrate a PHP website into an ASP.NET one, I've created a folder named "`pages`" in the ASP Project that didn't existed in the PHP project, so, the URL is like that:

```
http://localhost:10399/pages/Supermercado.aspx
```

The problem is, if I click on it again, or in any other link on the page, it adds the `/page/` part on the link causing it to get me into a **404 Page**.

Comment: Hard to help a coding problem with no code..

Comment: how did you do the redirection? please add them, it will be hard to help you without it.. i bet on a url rewrite regex issue btw..

Comment: basically you don't need pages in your url..m i right?

Comment: Please provide your code.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, I can't post the code, but I have fixed the problem. I just needed to put the '/' after the other url links, apparently something like 'href = default.aspx' will append with the current directory of the page, 'href = /default.aspx' will go to the root.